# My apache is very slow and crashing

Tags: apache-2.2, server-crashes

I have my VPS server installed apache2. 10,000 people connected to the sites, and it is now very slow, while my CPU is 1.25% and I/O is 20B/sec. I have free memory of 644 Mb and using is only 347.

My apache2.conf is now:

```
   StartServers          5
MinSpareServers       5
MaxSpareServers      10
MaxClients           20
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
```

KeepAlive  is off.

I can't find any reason why it is so slow. What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: This can be caused by several reasons other than the machine or apache itself. Slow DNS server, slow DB server (non-indexed), badly-written queries, etc... Was it slow before?